# printing in java sets a title somewhere to "Java Printing"

Tags: java, printing

The following code works, but when I print to the PDFCreator printer driver, its default title is "Java Printing". (I suspect this is true for Adobe Distiller as well, since if you [search google for PDFs with Java Printing](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Java%20Printing%22%20filetype:pdf), you get a lot of results.)

Is there a way to change this from "Java Printing" to another string?

```
package com.example.test.gui;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;

public class TestPrint implements Printable 
{
    @Override public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
        if (pageIndex != 0)
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        graphics.drawString("Hi there", 100, 100);
        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

    public void printPage() throws PrinterException
    {
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        boolean ok = job.printDialog();
        if (ok) {
            job.setPrintable(this);
            job.print();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new TestPrint().printPage();
        }
        catch (PrinterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried this setJobName( String jobName ) .

```
job.setJobName("New Printing Name");
```

The API says that it is the name of the document to be printed.

I am running my code on Ubuntu, it doesn't print the title, so I am unable to verify whether it works or not.

Comment: Hurray! that worked! Simple but it's confusing what does what with all these different objects.

Answer (score 7):

Same answer, but for [`DocPrintJob`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/DocPrintJob.html):

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet(); 
pras.add(new JobName("your job name", Locale.getDefault())); 

docPrintJob.print(docToPrint, pras);
```